# Making a Form as a reusable Control like FolderBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls

I have created a form that emulates a `FolderBrowseDialog`, but with some added features I wanted. It's tested and working, so now I want to make it into a control.
My problem is that as soon as I inherit from `UserControl` instead of `Form`, I no longer have a `Close()` method, and I no longer have a `FormClosing` event.
When I click on the OK or Cancel button, how do I close the form and return control to the calling object?

Answer (score 1):

To make it a reusable component, instead of trying to derive it from `Control`, create a [`Component`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) which uses that form. This way it can show in toolbox and you can drop an instance of your component on design surface like other components.

Your component should contain some properties which you want to expose from the dialog, also contain a `ShowDialog` method which created your form using some properties (like title, initial directory) and the shows your custom form as dialog and sets some properties (like selected folder) and returns the dialog result. For example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class MyFolderBrowser : Component
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string SelectcedFolder { get; set; }
    public DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        using (var f = new YourCustomForm() { Text = this.Text })
        {
            var result = f.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                SelectcedFolder = f.SelectedFolder;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.
However, I did find an alternate solution.I created a class library and then replaced the token class.cs that is created
with the classes of my form, and then just changed the namespace.
It works, but I like your solution better. It is a little cleaner.

Comment: If you don't make a component you can't use it in design time and you should only use it in code. But making a component enables you to drop an instance of it on your form like a real folder browser component, a timer and so on.